# How to Interpolate and Upsample columns in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following datasets:

```
Dataset A
2019-01-30 06:00:00 111
2019-01-30 07:00:00 333
2019-01-30 08:00:00 555
2019-01-30 09:00:00 111
2019-01-30 10:00:00 222
2019-01-30 11:00:00 444

Dataset B
2019-01-30 06:00:00 10
2019-01-30 06:30:00 30
2019-01-30 07:00:00 50
2019-01-30 07:30:00 10
2019-01-30 08:00:00 20
2019-01-30 08:30:00 40
2019-01-30 09:00:00 10
2019-01-30 09:30:00 30
2019-01-30 10:00:00 50
2019-01-30 10:30:00 10
2019-01-30 11:00:00 20
2019-01-30 11:30:00 40
```

I would like to use the coarser dataset to infill values in the higher resolution dataset. Ideally I would like to remain flexible in the way the filling can be done. For example at 06:30:00 the data could be filled in with either 111 or 333 depending if we are "forward" or "backward" filling. I suspect Pandas has an easy way to do that but I haven't find a neat solution when the two dataset have different sizes.

```
Desired Output
2019-01-30 06:00:00 111
2019-01-30 06:30:00 111
2019-01-30 07:00:00 333
2019-01-30 07:30:00 333
2019-01-30 08:00:00 555
2019-01-30 08:30:00 555
2019-01-30 09:00:00 111
2019-01-30 09:30:00 111
2019-01-30 10:00:00 222
2019-01-30 10:30:00 222
2019-01-30 11:00:00 444
2019-01-30 11:30:00 444
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dates'])
df2['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['dates'])

df = df1.set_index('dates').reindex(df2['dates'], method='ffill')
print (df)
                     val
dates                   
2019-01-30 06:00:00  111
2019-01-30 06:30:00  111
2019-01-30 07:00:00  333
2019-01-30 07:30:00  333
2019-01-30 08:00:00  555
2019-01-30 08:30:00  555
2019-01-30 09:00:00  111
2019-01-30 09:30:00  111
2019-01-30 10:00:00  222
2019-01-30 10:30:00  222
2019-01-30 11:00:00  444
2019-01-30 11:30:00  444
```

---

```
df = df1.set_index('dates').reindex(df2['dates'], method='bfill')
print (df)
                       val
dates                     
2019-01-30 06:00:00  111.0
2019-01-30 06:30:00  333.0
2019-01-30 07:00:00  333.0
2019-01-30 07:30:00  555.0
2019-01-30 08:00:00  555.0
2019-01-30 08:30:00  111.0
2019-01-30 09:00:00  111.0
2019-01-30 09:30:00  222.0
2019-01-30 10:00:00  222.0
2019-01-30 10:30:00  444.0
2019-01-30 11:00:00  444.0
2019-01-30 11:30:00    NaN
```